# How to do rational arithmetic in julia?

Tags: julia

I am writing some functions in julia and want the results to be represented as rational numbers. That is, if a function returns 1/2, 1/3, 13/2571 etc I want them to be returned as written and not converted to floats.  Say the functions compute some coefficients by some iterative process and I want the coefficient values to be shown as rationals. How can I do that in julia?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to do?  There's already a `Rational` type ([docs](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/complex-and-rational-numbers/#rational-numbers)), so if you set `x = 1//2`, it'll work.  (This is described in the first google hit for "Julia rationals", so I'm assuming you're after something more complicated.)

Comment: Well, what I want the functions to do is to make some computations of some coefficients in such a way as to naturally return rational numbers and not floats. So internal to the functions I want the arithmetic to create only rationals.  How to do that is my question.

Comment: So, maybe I simply can use Base.rationalize([Type],computed_coeff) to give the computed coefficient a 'cast' as a rational? If so, that's just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rationals in Julia can be written as

```
1//2
```

These will work with functions, including user-defined ones, as you would expect:

```
5//7*3//5 # results in 3//7

f(x) = x^2 - 1

f(3//4) # results in -7//16
```

There's really not much else to it, but see also the [manual section](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/complex-and-rational-numbers/#rational-numbers). If there's something in particular that's not working for you, post some example code and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks.  I will forge ahead and see what happens in my function construction and output. I appreciate the help.